# Problem accessing C++ server with C++ client

Tags: c++, sockets, rpc, thrift

C++ based Server `Something_server` has a method that prints ping

```
#include "Something.h"
#include <protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
#include <server/TSimpleServer.h>
#include <transport/TServerSocket.h>
#include <transport/TBufferTransports.h>

using namespace ::apache::thrift;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::transport;
using namespace ::apache::thrift::server;

using boost::shared_ptr;

using namespace Test;
        class SomethingHandler : virtual public SomethingIf {
     public:
      SomethingHandler() {
        // Your initialization goes here
      }

      int32_t ping() {
        // Your implementation goes here
        printf("ping\n");
       return 0;
      }

    };

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      int port = 9090;
      shared_ptr<SomethingHandler> handler(new SomethingHandler());
      shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new SomethingProcessor(handler));
      shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
      shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
      shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

      TSimpleServer server(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
      server.serve();
      return 0;
    }
```

`Something_client` is supposed to call this method in order to print out `"ping"`

```
  #include "Something.h"  // As an example

#include <transport/TSocket.h>
#include <transport/TBufferTransports.h>
#include <protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>

using namespace apache::thrift;
using namespace apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace apache::thrift::transport;

using namespace Test;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  boost::shared_ptr<TSocket> socket(new TSocket("localhost", 9090));
  boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
  boost::shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));

  SomethingClient client(protocol);
  transport->open();
  client.ping();
  transport->close();

  return 0;
}
```

instructions say "run the server and ping it with client"....no clue what this means...

I do

```
 ./Something_server
```

and nothing happens....as if the command were running forever and not terminating...so I am not quite sure how to proceed.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: As far as I understand you have two executables. First one is server and the second one is client. You should run the server. It runs forever. Then run the client and it will ping the server and then exit. On server's terminal you should see a "ping" output. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you should first run ./Something_server & (& puts the job in background so it doesnt clutter output).
Then you run ./Something_client which apparently pings the server.

Comment: AWESOME! the & command did it! where do I learn about "&" and stuff like that and is "ping" standard terminology for this sort of thing?

Comment: Ping: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping, Unix comand line:http://www.amazon.com/Unix-Programming-Environment-Prentice-Hall-Software/dp/013937681X